# Trouble accessing Parent controller scope (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, parent

am trying to go over AngularJS as a complete n00b, installed everything using Yeoman, grunt and bower.

I have been fiddling around with the code nicely but now am stuck at trying to access parent scope. See Code below

```
'use strict';

angular.module('castLibraryApp')
  .controller('library', function ($scope) {
    $scope.movies =  [
        {title: 'Sherlock Holmes', poster: 'http://bit.ly/19p8cla'},
        {title: 'Star Trek', poster: 'http://bit.ly/1eAagVa'},
      ];
    $scope.directory  = '~/Movies/';
    console.log($scope.movies);
  })
  .controller('movie', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.section  = 'View Movie';
    console.log($scope.movies);
  });
```

Library controller is called in my **main.html** template, while the movie controller is accessed in my **view.html** template. I want to print the information such as name and poster in the **view** template.

However I keep getting undefined variable

I know it my be a silly error but would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use `$scope.$parent` to access your `library` controller. But this is not a good design. Better you put your `movies` in service: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services

Answer (score 2):

In movie controller use

```
$scope.$parent.movies
```

and in view.html, use

```
{{ $parent.movies }}
```